# Elasticsearch configuration and settings for nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes

I have just installed ElasticSearch 5.0.0. When I run `localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v` it gives me ip as 10.57.203.16. But I want localhost as a server. Where should I configure it ?

Comment: is that the ip you're running ES and Logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add the below line to your `elasticsearch.yml` ,restart the ES and then try querying for the available nodes:

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

**EDIT:**

Try adding a `node name` in your `elasticsearch.yml` :

```
node.name: elastic_test1
```

Comment: Yes I have made two changes.

cluster.name: elastic_test
network.host: localhost
Should I make any other change ? But still it gives me same ip

Comment: Making your network.host: 127.0.0.1 gives the same problem?. Apart from that the yml should be fine. But according to [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5065) ticket, the returned address is the publish host.

Comment: Thanks...I have commented  "network.host: localhost" from yml file. Now by default it configure localhost as network.host.